# Generate JSON post build on .NET project

Tags: javascript, .net, enums, build

Im trying to generate javascript files containing the enums on my shared .NET library (so my web api and client will be synced automatically and no multiple code will be written).
I heard of .NET post-build event but not quite sure if we should and how to use it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered T4 template?

Comment: Can you give an example how to achieve what i was trying

Answer (score 1):

You can generate code via [T4 templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb126445.aspx).

To help yourself working with T4 templates I suggest you to download `AutoT4` and `Devart T4 editor`. AutoT4 will automatically execute the code generation tool associated with the T4 file every time you build your project (make sure the custom tool to run is 'TextTemplatingFileGenerator'); Devart T4 editor will provide text colorization and intellisense for T4 syntax. (From visualStudio go to Tools -> extensions and updates -> online and install those extensions)

You can use reflection to extract relevant information from you .NET classes and
output a .js file with that information correctly formatted.

I give you an example: I need to have behaviorless exact copies of some classes at layer boundaries in my application. In particular i need to have DTOs of EntityFramework entities so i wrote this T4 template that searches for entities and generates DTOs:

```
<#@ template hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ assembly Name="System.dll" #>
<#@ assembly Name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)EntityFramework.dll" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Data.Entity" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #> 
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#string _namespace ="DataTransferObjects";#>

namespace <#=_namespace#>
{
<#  
    var entityTypes = typeof(MyDbContext).GetProperties( BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance )
        .Where( property => property.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
        property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().ToString().Contains( "DbSet" ) )
        .Select( property => property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First() );

    foreach( var entityType in entityTypes )
    {
        Write($"\tpublic class {entityType.Name}{Environment.NewLine}");
        Write("\t{");
        Write(Environment.NewLine);

        var properties = entityType.GetProperties( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance );

        foreach(var property in properties )
        {
            var internalFormat = property.PropertyType.ToString();

            //assign special char to [] to preserve array notation
            internalFormat = internalFormat.Replace( "[]", "^" ); 
            var typeString =  Regex.Replace( internalFormat, @"`(\d)\[", "<" )
                .Replace( ']', '>' ).Replace( "^", "[]" );

            typeString= typeString.Replace(entityType.Namespace+".","");
            Write( $"\t\tpublic {typeString} {property.Name} {{get; set;}}{Environment.NewLine}" );                    
        }

        Write("\t}" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
    } 
#>
}
```

Following the same principles you can generate you javascript.
Hope this helps.